# Nest - respond to server side event

Tags: nest-api

I see examples in the Nest documentation that illustrate client side events (pushing values to the Nest device).  I want to go the other direction (respond to events triggered by the Nest device).

There appears to be one example in the Nest documentation for server-side Twitter integration, but its above my skill level and I can't read it.  Does this example illustrate what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You might whant to look at a (web)socket connection with the nest server. Then the server will send you a message everytime something changed. with this you can read what changed and trigger a event on that specific change.